# how to get access to x:Name from MVVM viewmodel

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I want to bind Microchart data from viewmodel to view in my xamarin prism application

i tried binding from backend c# by accessing the x:Name and its working fine.but i want to keep all my logic in viewmodel.is there any way to access this chart element from viewmodel.

my xaml code

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <StackLayout Padding="5,3,5,3" >

                        <microcharts:ChartView HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="200" x:Name="chartView"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Padding="5,3,5,3" >

                        <microcharts:ChartView HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="200" x:Name="chartView1"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Padding="5,3,5,3">

                        <microcharts:ChartView HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="200" x:Name="chartView2"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
```

and my backend c# code

```
var entries = new List<ChartEntry>
                        {
                            new ChartEntry(200)
                            {
                                Label = "January",
                                ValueLabel = "200",
                                Color = SKColor.Parse("#266489")
                            },
                            new ChartEntry(400)
                            {
                                Label = "February",
                                ValueLabel = "400",
                                Color = SKColor.Parse("#68B9C0")
                            },
                            new ChartEntry(100)
                            {
                                Label = "March",
                                ValueLabel = "100",
                                Color = SKColor.Parse("#90D585")
                            }
                        };
            var chart = new BarChart() { Entries = entries };
            var chart1 = new BarChart() { Entries = entries };
            var chart2 = new PointChart() { Entries = entries };
            // or: var chart = new LineChart() { Entries = entries };
            // or: var chart = new DonutChart() { Entries = entries };
            // or: var chart = new RadialGaugeChart() { Entries = entries };
            // or: var chart = new RadarChart() { Entries = entries };
            this.chartView.Chart = chart;
            this.chartView1.Chart = chart1;
            this.chartView2.Chart = chart2;
```

i want to move this backend c# code to viewmodel.and i dont know how to bind this chart data to view from viewmodel.Thanks

Comment: You cannot do this in my knowledge.

Comment: Use Binding for **Chart** Property.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this.

You can access xml side with BindingContext.

```
  <microcharts:ChartView HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="200" ValueLabel="{Binding your_prop}" x:Name="chartView"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok  I have a mediaelement I needed to be able to pause so I tried everyone's examples and fought error after error.   I got access in a very simple way to a x:Name element. in the XAML   I  named the view element

---

MainPage.xaml code for view element
set the name value for access in xaml.c code

---

```
<behaviors:MediaElement Source="{Binding VideoSource}"
    x:Name="MediaName"
    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
    WidthRequest="800" 
    HeightRequest="600"         
    ShowsPlaybackControls="True"                                           
    IsEnabled="{Binding CanVideoPlay}"
    IsVisible="{Binding CanSeeMedia}"                                      
    AutoPlay="True" 
    IsLooping="False"
    />
```

```
Now having a name property I then went into the MaiPage.xaml.c  and created a public mediaelement variable.  This could be any view element previously set with a x:name variable.  In your case it could be the ListView
```

---

MainPage.xaml.c
Notice the private set in the declaration, this is just good practice.

---

```
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;
    
    namespace VideoTest.Views
    {
        public partial class MainPage
        {
            public static MediaElement GlobalMediaName { get; private set; }
            public MainPage()
            {
               InitializeComponent();
                GlobalMediaName = MediaName;
    
            }
           
        }
    }
```

```
Now heading back into the ViewModel Code I was able to access any property I wanted on this element very simply by the following code call.
```

---

MainPageViewModel.c

---

```
  private void Closevideo()
  {             
     MC.MediaHasRunandHasCompleted();
     MainPage.GlobalMediaName.Pause();
  }
```

You can access any view element using this procedure.  I as others suggest, unless you have another way around, separation of view and viewmodel code are important.  In this particular case I needed to pause the video from playing.  The play and pause button were not readily available.